# Strange behaviour with sympy subs

Tags: python, sympy

I recently updated from sympy 0.7.4 to 0.7.6 and now I have some very strange behaviour with subs. The following code

```
from sympy.abc import phi
import sympy as sp

z=sp.Symbol('z')
t=sp.Symbol('t')
sp.pprint((phi(z,t).diff(t,2)).subs(phi(z,t).diff(z),sp.Symbol('b')(z,t)).expand())
```

gives me the output

2
 ∂
───(b(z, t))
  2
∂t

(second order time derivative of b)
but I would expect the output

2
 ∂
───(φ(z, t))
  2
∂t

(second order time derivative of phi, ie nothing gets substituted)

This was working perfectly in my previous version of sympy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug:

```
In [10]: phi(z,t).diff(t,2).subs(phi(z,t), b(z,t))
Out[10]: Derivative(b(z, t), t, t)

In [11]: phi(z,t).diff(t,2).subs(phi(z,t).diff(t), b(z,t))
Out[11]: Derivative(b(z, t), t)

In [12]: phi(z,t).diff(t,2).subs(phi(z,t).diff(z), b(z,t))
Out[12]: Derivative(b(z, t), t, t)
```

It seems that it's not taking into account the arguments of original derivative when they don't match the `subs` derivative argument.  Looks like it's already been reported https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9135